# Use Parcelable to pass an object from one android activity to another

Tags: android, object, android-activity, bundle, parcelable

I want to do this

```
class A extends Activity{
       private class myClass{
       }
       myClass obj = new myClass();

      intent i = new Intent();
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putParcelable(Constants.Settings, obj); //I get the error The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (int, A.myClass)
      i.setClass(getApplicationContext(),B.class);
      startActivity(i);  
    }
```

How do I use Parcelable to pass obj to activity B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error suggests, you need to make your class (`myClass` in this case) implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). If you look at the [documentation for `Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), all the `putParcelable` methods take either a `Parcelable` or a collection of them in some form. (This makes sense, given the name.) So if you want to use that method, you need to have a `Parcelable` instance to put in the bundle...

Of course you don't *have* to use `putParcelable` - you could implement `Serializable` instead and call `putSerializable`.

Comment: The way I have understood the Serializable interface is that it's used to support serialization and deserialization. How is that applicable here? 
Also, even if I implement Parcelable, how do I convert my object into a parcel? Could you point me to an example?

Comment: @Namratha: You're trying to pass information around, which is precisely what serialization is there for. If you're working within the same process, you don't need a bundle at all, as far as I can tell - but if you need to pass information between processes, serialization in one form or other is what you're talking about.

Comment: I see. But I read here http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/ that Serializable is associated with a performance hit whereas Parcelable is not. Also I'm still having trouble trying to convert  my object into a Parcelable instance.

Comment: @Namratha: The performance hit there isn't quantified (and that was two years ago). I only gave it as another *option* - if you can use Parcelable, then go for it. It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm only trying to pass my custom object to another activity(class B) so that I can call methods on that object which will modify member variable of class A. I understand that I have to implement the Parcelable interface and in the writeToParcel method I have to write the fields into the parcel. Now, given that my custom class contains only methods and no member variables, how to I convert this into a Parcelable?

Comment: @Namratha: If the custom class as no member variables, there's no useful *information* in it to start with - so what are you really trying to pass?

Comment: I want activity B to be able to call methods on the object that I instantiate in activity A. I basically want to pass an object that I can call the implemented methods on.

Comment: @Namratha: But if there's no *data* in the object, then really all that's of interest is the class itself, right? Is it always the same class? If so, I don't see that any useful information is being exchanged.

Comment: Yes, it's the class itself that contains the methods. Yes, it's always the same class.

Comment: And does that class have any variables you want to preserve? That's the important bit of serialization, usually.

Answer (score 7):

Create your class and implements **Serializable**:

```
private class myClass implements Serializable  {
   }
```

And do like:

```
myClass obj = new myClass();
Intent aActivity = (A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("object", obj);
```

On Receiving side:

```
myClass myClassObject = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("object");
```

Comment: I think you mean Intent aActivity = new Intent(A.this, B.class); ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Parcelable is pain in writing code but more cost effective than Serializable. Have a look at the given below link -

[Parcelable Vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)