# How to navigate data between activity and fragment of other activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs

It may be dumb question but it is still confusing how to pass navigate data from activity to fragment of other activity how can i achieve this i have searched and tired still i cannot find anything can somebody help me out.  Now let me tell my requirement am having tabactivity in one of the tab i have listview when i click listivew item it must goes to other activity where the data will go and populate the listview in tabs how can i achieve this so far what i have tried is 
This is my tab activity:
package servicefiirst.precision.activitiestabs;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                            Task task=new Task();
                            return task;

                    case 1:
                            Calls calls=new Calls();
                            return calls;

                }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           switch (position){
               case 0:
                   return "Task";
               case 1:
                   return "Call";

            }
        return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the fragment where listview getspopulated:

```
package servicefiirst.precision.activitiestabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 08-01-2016.
 */
public class Task extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yog,container,false);

         Listview lv=(Listview)rootview.findviewbyId(R.id.lv);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(
           @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity,DetailActivity.class)
          startactivity(intent);
        }
    });



        return rootview;
    }




}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity

Comment: Simply add a indicator to your intent, `intent.putExtra("flag", positionOfYourClickedItem)`, retrieve it with `Bundle` and `getIntent().getExtras()` in the next `Activity`and load your Data in it.

Comment: my doubt is need to pass object from one activity and need to populate listview in fragment of another acitivyut

Answer (score 2):

Use a bundle to transfer data from one activity to another activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_NAME", "Abrakadabra");
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivityName.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i)  <-- new activity started
```

Then in the receiving activity: Put this code in the onCreate method

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringdata = bundle.getString("KEY_NAME");
```

To pass data from activity to fragment: Put this code anywhere

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_NAME", "Abrakadabra");
MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in the onCreateView method of the fragment add this code

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String stringdata = args.getString("KEY_NAME");
```

Comment: THIS IS OK FOR STRING BUT I NEED TO PASS OBJECTS TO POPULATE LISTIVEW HOW COME I DO

Comment: use putStringArrayList and getStringArrayList respectively for list

check this link if you are passing images, audio as bundle using a loop and then for the list extract them back using a loop

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975239/use-parcelable-to-pass-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another

Comment: Please mark it answered if it solved the problem mentioned in the query. It would help others in future

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sending data to another activity

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                String source = c.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MetroFrom.this, Metro.class);
                intent.putExtra("From", source);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Then put this code on which activity you want to receive data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        etsource.setText(intent.getStringExtra("from"));
```